# RooEntity is not mapped

Tags: hibernate, spring-roo, hibernate-mapping

I'm using SpringRoo to handle the Hibernation of my entity objects.

But when running unit tests, they are failing because it says the entity is not mapped:

Here is the error:

QuerySyntaxException: COUPON is not mapped [SELECT o FROM COUPON o]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)

This is what my persistence unit is configured like:

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitTest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is how my entity is defined:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity(identifierColumn = "COUPONID", identifierType = Integer.class, table = "COUPON")
public class Coupon {
```

The application context is set:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tamiflu.entities">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
</context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitTest"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:tamiflu"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
</bean>
```

I feel like I have everything in place.  I don't know why the @RooEntity isn't being picked up as being mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Mikko Maunu is right, your SELECT is not correct for JPA, the correct one is SELECT o FROM Coupon o.

@RooJpaActiveRecord is the new annotation for the incoming release of Roo: 1.2 (currently in RC1), and @Entity is the one for the current 1.1.5 and previous versions of Roo.

If the problem persists:

1. Review your Entity. Roo generates the method in an AspectJ file (.aj extension, something like _Roo_Entity or _Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord), but you can move (or push it in) to the Java file. See if the **find methods have the correct syntax** (you have to use the name of the Entity instead of the name of the table, as Mikko Maunu said)
2. Review the scanned packages. Find in your applicationContext the context:component-scan element and see if the Entity you want to load belongs to a sub-package of the base-package, com.tamiflu.entities in your case.

A note for the second point: Roo creates code that loads the application context files using wild cards.

Be careful if you have more than one, because the order is not guaranteed (if you have several files with different packages to scan, you will have issues loading entities, unless you force the order removing the wild cards and manually specifying the desired order for the applicationContext.xml files)